# How can I add Microsoft Store app to a windows 10 laptop, which doesn't seem to have it ever installed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

Main Problem:

- I need to back up my company provided iPhone so that I can upgrade
  from iphone-7 to iphone-11, as my phone almost 4 years old can not hold charge more than 30
  minutes of application use
- I need to backup to my company provided
  laptop as 5 GB iCloud storage is not enough. I need to install iTunes
  for windows.
- My laptop is under company's group policy I do not have
  Microsoft Store app installed.
- I tried about 20 different things I
  found on google to enable MS Store and none of them worked.
- I downloaded iTunes executable from some obscure spot at apple I
  installed it using my secondary account with local admin privileges.
- As soon as I launched it it said a newer version available but when I
  clicked on it, it did not install or did nothing for that matter.

Problem:

- When my iphone is connected to the laptop via USB/lightning cable, I
  am getting 0xE8000068 unknown error occurred message.
- I spent more than an hour with apple genius bar idiots' including a so-called
  dummy supervisor Their diagnosis of this problem is:"I do not have
  the latest iTunes and have to install that"
- My answer to that:   No-shit Sherlock, but I can not do it w/o MS store and MS store is
  not available to me.

My gut feeling:

- If I can install MS Store app using my admin credentials and install
  itunes that way, I will have none of this crap. I might be wrong but
  it seems to be the least resistance method right now.
- Hence my question: How can I install the Microsoft store app to my windows 10
  laptop? I am already logged in under my local admin enabled account.

Comment: This question belongs on [su] instead, as it is not programming related. Also, if your company's group policy won't allow MS Store to be installed, your local admin account cannot override that setting. Privileges trickle down from the top to the bottom, and lower levels cannot bypass the settings established by higher levels.

Comment: use this [site](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) to get the appx links to the app and all dependencies. now install the appx files to get it

Comment: Type this command in a powershell prompt to see if Store is really not installed :
 `Get-AppXPackage "Microsoft.windowsStore"`